# How to redistribute Ubuntu(Linux)?

Tags: customization, custom-distributions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to customize live Ubuntu CD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd)

I have Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Ubuntu/Kubuntu and Server) and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and Other linux distributions. I want to change its backgrounds and packages in the ISO image, so when I Install it, the modified versions are installed. And I want to redistribute the modified version.

I also want to replace the kernel with a new kernel, in the ISO.

In short, I want to customize Ubuntu (or any linux distribution) and distribute the custom version.

Comment: This doesn't deserve a downvote. atleast not after the edit. Perfectly valid question.

Comment: @gertvdijk I think the intention here is to ask a question about rebranding. Unfortunately, as you say, this is too broad, and the answers so far have addressed other aspects of the question. **Shivan Pandya**: If you want to ask specifically about replacing Canonical trademarked elements like Ubuntu logos, I recommend asking a new question about that (or search...we have at least one question about debranding, it *might* be what you're looking for).

Comment: *(should post this on meta)* I hate it when my comment is removed by the system just because it mentioned the duplicate question.

Comment: @ShivamPandya This question was too broad before, asking about how to do multiple, separate things. (For example, debranding and kernel replacement are not the same thing, and the only way to address both was to dupe this to [a very general question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-live-ubuntu-cd).) Your recent edit makes this *way more general*, without making it more specific in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ubuntu-builder`. More information can be found on its Launchpad page:

[ubuntu-builder [image: Launchpad logo]](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu-builder)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

There is a page in the [Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization) on this topic. Newer kernels like the quantal kernel are available in 12.04 as packages, so this should also work. Please note that you very likely do not have the rights to release your custom spin under the Ubuntu brand on the internet and you shouldn't do so in the first place.

What do you mean by redistribution anyway? Just have your custom image somewhere hosted on the internet or using it in your department/company?

Comment: I Just want to make an image from any existing linux image, with my name, and it is not for any department or company. its for my study purpose only.

Comment: What do you mean Ubuntu Brand, the main reason people find this page IMO is that they are wondering if its OK to share a custom ISO. IE: Can I host a custom Ubuntu Desktop ISO on my website?

Comment: @FreeSoftwareServers http://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/intellectual-property-policy

Comment: You can redistribute Ubuntu, but only where there has been no modification to it. :) That answers that very clearly, thank you!